# If a set is bounded from $m$ to $M$, is it a proprer subset of the segment [m,M]?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book I read it is stated:

> A set $X \subset  \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, if and only if when $\exists m,M \in  \mathbb{R}:\forall x \in X \space$ $m\leq x \leq M$, **i.e. X $\subset [m,M]$**

At the same time, earlier, author defines $\subset$ symbol as a proper subset symbol, i.e. a subset of some set, that does not contain all elements from the set.

Considering this fact I am confused why author states, that bounded set is a proper subset of the segment $[m,M]$, if condition of boundness contains less than and higher than **or equal** signs, so bounded subset can be non-proper subset of $[m,M]$. Of course, it can be, and it cannot be, but in the book, it is confusing, so I just want to be sure, that $X\subseteq[m,M]$ also can be true.

---

I just understood, that it does not matter, how author defined it earlier, since She wrote, that a bounded set is $X⊂R$
, so it apriori means a proper subset. Since author used "if and only if, when" it seems to be surely confusing.

Comment: Sure, $X \subseteq [m, M]$ is fine too, but note that the given definition only requires *existence* of such $m$ and $M$; enlarging the closed interval $[m, M]$ doesn't change it.

Comment: @JakobStreipel, I just understood, that it does not matter, how author defined it earlier, since She wrote, that a bounded set is $X⊂R$, so it apriori means a proper subset. So it seems to be a typo, do not You think? Since author used "if and only if, when" it seems to be wrong

Comment: The "when" is a bit awkward, sure, but there is nothing wrong with the definition (other than $X \subset \mathbb R$ maybe implying that $\mathbb R$ is neither bounded not unbounded, depending on what follows this definition in the text, but that's really neither here nor there).

Comment: @JakobStreipel, whatever, $X⊆[m,M]$ is also correct, so it is was I was asking about, thanks

Comment: At any rate my point in the first comment is that $X \subseteq [m, M]$ implies $X \subset [m-\varepsilon, M+\varepsilon]$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: @JakobStreipel, what it is the sense of such expression? Just another way to define $X⊆[m,M]$ or I miss something?

Comment: The use of the proper subset symbol is perfectly fine since even if the set $X$ you're testing for boundedness satisfies $X = [m, M]$ (and hence not $X \subset [m, M]$), *some other* real numbers $m'$ and $M'$ can be used in their place for which $X \subset [m', M']$.